# Tricky question about Ito's stochastic integral and continal law

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Consider $B=(B_t)_{t\geq 0}$ real $\mathcal F_t$ - brownian motion  starting at zero, in a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, (\mathcal F_t)_{t\geq 0}, \mathbb P)$. Then, consider a new real $\mathcal F_t$ - brownian motion $\tilde{B}=(\tilde{B_0})_{t\geq t}$ independent of $B$ as weel as a process $H=(H_t)_{t\geq 0}$ given by

$$ H_t := \frac{1}{\int _0^t f^2(B_s) ~ds}\int _0^t f(B_s) ~d \tilde B_s \mathbf 1_{\{ \int _0^t f^2(B_s) ~ds>0\}}, \ t\geq 0,$$

where $f \in \mathcal C^0(\mathbb R, \mathbb R)$ and $f \not\equiv 0$.

What is the conditional distribution of $H_t$ knowing $B$?

I dont have any idea on how to start to approach it. Any advice will be strongly appreciate. Thank's in advance.

Crossposted on [overflow.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132070/conditional-law-of-an-itos-stochastic-integral)

Comment: I've noticed that you have asked quite a few questions recently. I wanted to make sure that you are aware of the quotas 50 questions/30 days and 6 questions/24 hours, so that you can plan posting your questions accordingly. (If you try to post more questions, stackexchange software will not allow you to do so.) For more details see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4770/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered on [overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132070/conditional-law-of-an-itos-stochastic-integral) by The Bridge.

$$ \mathcal L(H_t| B) = \mathcal N (0,1)$$
 since the integral which defines $H$ is a Wiener integral if  we know the all path of $B$.